# How to add column filter for each column in magento grid for custom module

Tags: magento, grid

I've been writing a custom module for the magento backend,i want to add filter for each column

Can anyone point me in the right direction as to where the code is that handles this function? I'm going to assume its part of the controller

Thanks for any help you can provide!

i have prepared columns like this

```
     public function __construct()
{
    parent::__construct();
    $this->setId('main_grid');
$this->setDefaultSort('entity_id');
    $this->setDefaultDir('DESC');
    $this->setSaveParametersInSession(true);
    $this->setUseAjax(true);

}

protected function _prepareCollection()
{

    $model = Mage::getModel('CartAbandoned/tip');
            $collection = $model->getCollection();
        $this->setCollection($collection);
            return parent::_prepareCollection();
}


    $this->addColumn('id', array(
        'header'        => Mage::helper('CartAbandoned')->__('Id'),
        'align'         => 'right',
        'width'         => '50px',
        'type'          => 'number',
        'index'         => 'entity_id',
    ));

    $this->addColumn('E-Mail', array(
        'header'        => Mage::helper('CartAbandoned')->__('EMail'),
        'align'         => 'left',
        'width'         => '150px',
        'index'         => 'customer_email',
        'type'          => 'text',
        'truncate'      => 50,
        'escape'        => true,
   ));

    $this->addColumn('firstName', array(
        'header'        => Mage::helper('CartAbandoned')->__('firstName'),
        'align'         => 'left',
        'index'         => 'customer_firstname',
        'type'          => 'text',
        'escape'        => true,
   ));

    $this->addColumn('lastName', array(
        'header'        => Mage::helper('CartAbandoned')->__('lastName'),
        'align'         => 'left',
        'index'         => 'customer_lastname',
        'type'          => 'text',
        'escape'        => true,
      ));

$this->addColumn('total', array(
        'header'        => Mage::helper('CartAbandoned')->__('Total'),
        'align'         => 'left',
        'index'         => 'base_grand_total',
        'type'          => 'price',
        'escape'        => true,
 ));

$this->addColumn('quan', array(
        'header'        => Mage::helper('CartAbandoned')->__('Quantity'),
        'align'         => 'left',
        'index'         => 'items_qty',
        'type'          => 'number',
        'escape'        => true,
 ));

    $this->addColumn('cartcreatedtime', array(
        'header'        => Mage::helper('CartAbandoned')->__('cartcreatedtime'),
        'align'         => 'left',
        'index'         => 'created_at',
        'type'          => 'datetime',
        'escape'        => true,
 ));

   $this->addColumn('cartabandonedtime', array(
        'header'        => Mage::helper('CartAbandoned')->__('cartabandonedtime'),
        'align'         => 'left',
        'index'         => 'updated_at',
        'type'          => 'datetime',
        'escape'        => true,
));


     $this->addColumn('action',array(
            'header'    => Mage::helper('CartAbandoned')->__('Action'),
            'type'      => 'action',
            'getter'    => 'getId',
            'actions'   => array(
                array(
                    'caption' => Mage::helper('CartAbandoned')->__('View Products'),
                    'url'     => array('base'=>'*/*/edit'),
                    'field'   => 'id'
               )
           ),
           'filter'    => false,
           'sortable'  => false
    ));
```

Comment: Please clarify your question.  Are you asking where to put this snippet of code?  If not please be more specific about what you are trying to find.

Comment: Are you following a tutorial to guide you? And if not, why not?

Answer (score 1):

First of all search project by this term "extends Mage_Adminhtml_Block_Widget_Grid", you should find for example this class `Mage_Adminhtml_Block_Catalog_Category_Tab_Product`.

Basically what you need to focus on are two methods:

- `_prepareCollection()`
- `_prepareColumns()`

**`_prepareCollection`** prepares collection which is used by your grid and on which Magento applies filters which are represented by `index` key in each column that you add in **`_prepareColumns()`** method.

**Example**

Below example comes from class that i've pasted above ;)

```
$this->addColumn('E-Mail', array(
    'header'        => Mage::helper('CartAbandoned')->__('EMail'),
    'align'         => 'left',
    'width'         => '150px',
    'index'         => 'customer_email',
    'type'          => 'text',
    'truncate'      => 50,
    'escape'        => true,
```

));

In your collection there should be field/column which is called `customer_email` and as you have `index` set to same name Magento should handle rest.

**EDIT**

```
protected function _prepareCollection()
{
    $collection = Mage::getModel('catalog/product')->getCollection()
        ->addAttributeToSelect('name')
        ->addAttributeToSelect('sku');

    $this->setCollection($collection);

    return parent::_prepareCollection();
}

protected function _prepareColumns()
{
    $this->addColumn('entity_id', array(
        'header'    => Mage::helper('catalog')->__('ID'),
        'sortable'  => true,
        'width'     => '60',
        'index'     => 'entity_id'
    ));
    $this->addColumn('name', array(
        'header'    => Mage::helper('catalog')->__('Name'),
        'index'     => 'name'
    ));
    $this->addColumn('sku', array(
        'header'    => Mage::helper('catalog')->__('SKU'),
        'width'     => '80',
        'index'     => 'sku'
    ));

    return parent::_prepareColumns();
}
```

This example show how to prepare filterable collection for 3 columns: sku, name and entity_id.

Comment: please give me the idea about how to write _prepareCollection() with filters

Comment: it gives me error that call to undefined function addAttributeToSelect()

Answer (score 1):

There is one solution, which I found on atwix.com

```
$this->addColumn('address', array(
            'header'=> Mage::helper('sales')->__('Address'),
            'type'  => 'text',
            'renderer' => 'Atwix_Ordersgrid_Block_Adminhtml_Sales_Order_Renderer_Address',
            'filter_condition_callback' => array($this, '_addressFilter'),
));
```

as you can see we have added one more value `filter_condition_callback`

and the only thing we need is to add this protected method, which allow us add filtration:

```
protected function _addressFilter($collection, $column)
{
    if (!$value = $column->getFilter()->getValue()) {
        return $this;
    }

    $this->getCollection()->getSelect()->where(
        "sales_flat_order_address.city like ?
        OR sales_flat_order_address.street like ?
        OR sales_flat_order_address.postcode like ?"
    , "%$value%");


    return $this;
}
```

Full article you can find here: http://www.atwix.com/magento/grid-filter-for-columns/

Comment: can you helped for my question? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/31269519/grid-column-filter-not-working-with-multiple-values-in-magento-custom-module